# How can I post an image to a REST enpoint as application/json data with axios?

Tags: javascript, json, axios

I need to send image data to a rest endpoint that only processes `application/json` data.

I have the following axios code that works for endpoints that processes `multipart/form-data` data:

```
      let data = new FormData();
      canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        data.append("image", blob);
        this.loading = true;
        axios
          .post(this.annotateUrl, data, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
          })
```

Based on tutorial I have found, I thought this should work. But the endpoint doesn't seem to be getting any data.

```
      canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        let data = {
          image: blob
        }
        this.loading = true;

        axios
          .post(this.annotateUrl, data, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          })
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: what is `blob` and what is the resultant *string* value of `data.image`

Comment: blob is the object handle returned by [canvas.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically add your image to an html canvas and call the canvas's '[toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)' method to encode the image as a string. You can then send the encoded string as a JSON's property.

Comment: The strange thing is that now the code throws an exception, because of this [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default)

How is that possible. I'm sure the response headers include the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Comment: You can refer this to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image  for the solution to your problem. You basically need to add the 'data:' origin to your img-src directive in the content-security-policy header.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ajay Ullal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59260265/3985338), I wrote this code that does the trick:

```
let canvas = this.$parent.image.raster.canvas;

let dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
let data = { image: dataurl };
this.loading = true;

axios
  .post(this.annotateUrl, data, {
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
  .then([...])
  .catch([...])
  .finally([...])
```

As a side note, I noticed that axios starts the communication with a preflight OPTIONS call around [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which made things a bit more complicated. I recommend keeping an eye on the debug console of your browser for error/warning messages.